# Upgrading Postgres from 9.3 to 9.6 changed the type of a column's default value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am working on upgrading my application from Postgres 9.3 to 9.6. For the development environment I uninstalled 9.3 and installed 9.6.2, then imported my database. Since this is a Rails app, I have a `db/structure.sql` - I noticed after running migrations that there were a few differences in this file. Specifically the `DEFAULT` for a few columns went from type `character varying` to type `text` (however the column type itself did not change):

`-rewards_tracker_type character varying DEFAULT 'rewards_tracker'::character varying,
+rewards_tracker_type character varying DEFAULT 'rewards_tracker'::text,`

I'm guessing this is because the default value is of a known length but would appreciate a non guess.

Comment: I just tried this manually using `pg_dump` and `psql`, and I could not observe such a behaviour. How exactly did you upgrade the database? However, it does not matter much, because `text` and `character varying` are really the same thing in PostgreSQL.

Comment: We're using `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` - this answer points to them basically being interchangeable: https://serverfault.com/a/240907/260945